# Crash on my iOS game with server connection

Tags: ios, cocos2d-iphone, asihttprequest

I'm having some issues on my app: when you play a game, and the time finishes, the server will send the score you have made. When the internet is down, the app still send the request, when internet is on again, the app crashes. The console shows me this:

```
2013-05-31 11:00:34.376 xxxxxxx [1721:1be03] *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSRangeException', reason: '*** -[__NSArrayM objectAtIndex:]: index 0 beyond bounds for empty array'
*** First throw call stack:
(0x3352012 0x2754e7e 0x32f40b4 0xad260 0xacc1b 0xacb95 0xa770c 0x29ce3 0xa743b 0x68e04 0x68b0b 0x874b8 0x27686b0 0x1e1f765 0x32d5f3f 0x32d596f 0x32f8734 0x32f7f44 0x32f7e1b 0x358a7e3 0x358a668 0x1323ffc 0x65a9a 0x28e5 0x1)
libc++abi.dylib: terminate called throwing an exception
```

can someone tell me what is wrong?

**EDIT:**

I put an exception breakpoint and found that here is where the problem origins. This is the parse od the server response, which are separated with pipes:

```
-(void)parseNextGameScoresStatWithResponse:(NSString *)response{
    /*Response
     Position|username|totalscore|country|
     */
    if(response.length == 0 )
        return;

    NSString * cuttedString = [response substringFromIndex:1];

    NSMutableArray *responsesArray = [NSMutableArray arrayWithArray:[cuttedString componentsSeparatedByString:@"|"]];

    if(responsesArray.count != 0)
       [responsesArray removeLastObject];
    else{
        return;
    }

  //  NSLog(@"responsesArray = %@", responsesArray);

    self.statsArray = [NSMutableArray arrayWithCapacity:0];

    for (int i = 0; i < [responsesArray count]-1; i+=4) {
        StatModel *stat = [[StatModel alloc] init];
        stat.position = [[responsesArray objectAtIndex:i] intValue];
        stat.userName = [responsesArray objectAtIndex:i+1];
        stat.totalScore = [[responsesArray objectAtIndex:i+2] intValue];
        stat.countryCode = [responsesArray objectAtIndex:i+3];
  //      NSLog(@"stat of next game scores = %d %@ %d %@",stat.position, stat.userName, stat.totalScore, stat.countryCode);
        [self.statsArray addObject:stat];
        [stat release];
    }
}
```

Comment: Your are trying to access the first element of an empty array. If you require further help, please show some code.

Comment: @MarcusAdams Hi, yes I would like some help please. What do you need?

Comment: make sure the array exists..

Comment: Updated, added where the problem happens.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that even if `[responseArray count]` is `0`, it still enters the for loop.

Change your loop from:

```
for (int i = 0; i < [responsesArray count]-1; i+=4) {
  ..
```

To:

```
int i = 0;
while (i < [responsesArray count]) {
    StatModel *stat = [[StatModel alloc] init];
    stat.position = [[responsesArray objectAtIndex:i++] intValue];
    stat.userName = [responsesArray objectAtIndex:i++];
    stat.totalScore = [[responsesArray objectAtIndex:i++] intValue];
    stat.countryCode = [responsesArray objectAtIndex:i++];
    [self.statsArray addObject:stat];
    [stat release];
}
```